# Delete a keyboard layout in Windows 11

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, windows-11, input-languages

For some reason, I have an Icelandic keyboard installed (probably due to a misclick in Windows setup):

[image: Keyboard selector: English, Japanese, Icelandic]

However, Icelandic is not in the list of my languages:

[image: Language settings: English and Japanese]

Why the disparity, and more importantly, how do I remove it? Unlike the previous versions of Windows, keyboard layouts are now sorted under their respective languages... With no Icelandic language, I have no access to the Icelandic keyboard layout settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Adding* Icelandic to your languages should allow you to remove it again.

Internally, keyboard layout configuration is still stored in the same place in the Registry as before and doesn't *really* have a relationship with the Windows language list.

Open `regedit` and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload`, then delete the languages you don't need – the language identifier for English is `0409`, Icelandic is `040f`, Japanese is `0411` ([related list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs?view=windows-11)). See also [these instructions](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/registry/tree/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Keyboard-Layout/index).

Comment: Installing Icelandic made it show up twice in the keyboard layout selector. I could not remove Icelandic layout from there, presumably since it was the only one. Removing Icelandic language removed the second Icelandic layout, but the first one is still there. However, restarting did help.